# Liferay theme development

Tags: themes, liferay

I would like to ask a question on theming in  liferay. What would be easier and better? Create a New Theme or Modify a Theme that is already present for liferay pages?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the same: by creating a new theme with Liferay SDK the default theme will be cloned and then you can override some css, templates etc.

To create a new theme: http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/creating-a-the-4

Comment: Yes I did find that, I was actually asking which would be better or easier? As in with time constraints and all ?

Comment: Well as Mark has said they're the same because when use the Plugins SDK to create a theme it clones the default so you never need to create one from scratch. You only have to modify the existing (cloned) one.

Comment: Create liferay theme with liferay plugin sdk is the best way to do that!

Answer (score 2):

> When you create a theme in sdk, it's built upon parent theme or classic theme.

For reference, please check the build.xml of themes.

Answer (score 0):

As someone who has made several custom themes, its best to modify the existing theme. 
All your files YOU should modify are under /docroot/diffs/*

For images, I create a /custom folder under images where I put all mine.

For templates, I mainly modified the navigation.vm and portal_normal.vm files. I changed the way the navigation was handled completely.

I also modified the css drastically to achieve the look and feel we wanted. I created a custom.css file for that.

This is a custom sub navigation menu I created that allows the over state to be present when on child elements.

```
<nav id="navigation_sub_menu">
<ul>
    #foreach ($nav_item in $nav_items)

        #if ($nav_item.isSelected() && $nav_item.hasChildren())
            <ul class="child-menu">
                #foreach ($nav_child in $nav_item.getChildren())
                    #set ($nav_child_upper = $nav_child.getName())
                    #if ($nav_child.isSelected())
                        <li class="sub_menu">
                            <a class="selected" href="$nav_child.getURL()" $nav_child.getTarget()>$nav_child_upper.toUpperCase()</a>
                        </li>
                    #else
                        <li>
                            <a href="$nav_child.getURL()" $nav_child.getTarget()>$nav_child_upper.toUpperCase()</a>
                        </li>
                    #end
                #end
            </ul>
        #end
    #end
</ul>
```